# How to read the text from another computer

Tags: c#, .net, file, ip-address, readfile

I have tried to read the file from other computer using the IP address, but i could not able to read that one.It's raised the exception like "Could not find a part of the path 'E:\IPFile_Read\IPFile_Read\bin\Debug\@\IPAddress\Test\News.txt'"

Code:

```
 {

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("@\\IPaddress\\Test\\News.txt");
                line = sr.ReadLine();

                while (line != null)
                {
                    text_Data.Text = line;
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
                sr.Close();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

How can i read the text file from another computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"@\\IPaddress\\Test\\News.txt"` should be `@"\\IPaddress\Test\News.txt"`. For verbatim strings, the `@` goes *before* the opening quote, and if you're using a verbatim string, you don't need to escape the slashes. The UNC prefix still needs the `\\`, because it really does have two backslashes.